# how do I know if npm is installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

yesterday, I just installed the node.js using nvm on my mac.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/nvm
$ . ~/nvm/nvm.sh
$ nvm install 0.8.20
```

my understanding is the npm will be installed with the node.js. and I did see the npm folder inside node v0.8.20.

```
feelexits-Mac:bin feelexit$ pwd
/Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/lib/node_modules/npm/bin

feelexits-Mac:bin feelexit$ ls
node-gyp-bin        npm         npm-cli.js      npm.cmd         read-package-json.js
```

however,I've run into an issue though, when I run npm, no matter what I'm doing, I get the error "command not found"

**UPDATE:**

after added the directory to the path, still have problem.

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/lib/node_modules/npm/bin

feelexits-Mac:bin feelexit$ npm
/Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm: line 12: node: command not found
```

Comment: AFAIK after using nvm you should use 
`nvm use v0.8.XX` (your freshly installed version)
command too in order to start using 
the node.

Comment: @Sergey Benner, thank you so much. I should use "nvm use" to activate it.

Comment: NP. have a good one mate.